# react-medium-image-zoom show high quality image onclick

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, react-medium-image-zoom

I use the library react-medium-image-zoom

```
<Zoom>
    <img src={photo.thumbnail} />
</Zoom>
```

I have high quality image {photo.photo} and I want to use it when user zoom image thumbnail. I've tried `<Zoom zoomImg={photo.photo} >` but it doesn't work unfortunately. How can I add the original image onZoom?
I found in documentation

```
  // Higher quality image attributes to use on zoom.
  zoomImg?: ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>
```

But don't understand how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
zoomImg={{ src: photo.photo }}
```